# How to share mysql server on local network base connection with one computer to another?

Tags: php, mysql, networking, network-programming

I am trying to share mysql server on my local network but field to connect this server with one PC to another with follow this method.
https://www.brightfunction.co.uk/connecting-to-mysql-server-across-a-local-windows-network/

When trying to connect to the database with MySQL Workbench:

[image]

please help to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Which step did you fail? Was there any error message?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pct79e

Comment: check this shot

Comment: What is the IP address of your MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) name for server hostname for MySQL connection. You need to use the [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) for the Hostname instead.

If you don't know it, please read [this instruction](https://kb.netgear.com/20878/Finding-your-IP-address-without-using-the-command-prompt) for how to get the IP address of your Windows 10 machine. You should probably [setup your server to have a fixed IP](https://portforward.com/networking/static-ip-windows-10.htm), too.